# Thymeleaf decorator problem after upgrading spring boot to greater than 2.5.4

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have a MVC application based on spring-boot:2.5.4.

After migrating from spring-boot 2.5.4, to 2.5.14-2.6.7 Thymeleaf layout does'nt import header (header tag is empty) and leaves blank other inserted elements( like layouts/sidebar :: sidebar, layouts/footer :: footer) from the decorator.

I have upgraded my libs to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Main layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!-- JS/ CSS-->
</head>
<body id="page-top">

    <div th:replace="layouts/sidebar :: sidebar"></div>

    <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div id="content">
          <div layout:fragment="content"></div>
        </div>
        <footer class="sticky-footer bg-white">
            <div th:replace="layouts/footer :: footer">
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

and Page uwing this layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorator="layouts/base_layout"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
<section layout:fragment="content">
       some content
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Has there been a change in spring-boot thymeleaf compability? When I define header a sa fragment, I can import header to the pages, but this is missing the point of having a layout class, when I have to import every element manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was albe to fix my issue by reading [migration notes for Thymeleaf](https://ultraq.github.io/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/migrating-to-3.0/).

The section:

> This was deprecated back in 2.0 (thymeleaf-layout-dialect/issues/95)
> in favour of decorate as the naming was misleading, and has now been
> deleted.

So after replacing

```
layout:decorator
```

with

```
layout:decorate
```

Everything works fine.

Comment: Thank you! I read the notes too but somehow skimmed over it. Cost me more hours than I'd like to admit :D